# Hybrid absolute / fixed positioning behavior with CSS or Javascript?

Tags: jquery, html, css, positioning, css-position

I need to position a div in the bottom left corner of a container that has a real height of 100% of the browser window. The container has movement. Is it possible with css or even jQuery to get a child div positioned in the bottom left hand corner of a container?

That is something a hybrid behavior like this:

```
<div id="container">
   <span class="blc">i'm here!</span>
</div>

.blc{
   position:fixed; bottom:0px;
   position:absolute; left:0px; 
}
```

I've provided an example on JSFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/DeRwm/

[image]

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add following css:

```
#container{
 position:relative;
}

.blc{
   position:absolute;
   left:0px; 
   bottom:0px;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DeRwm/1/  thanks it worked, now if i could only get it to work on my developing code!